# SQL, during query create new column based on data conditions

Tags: sql, date, conditional-statements

I've managed to cobble together a SQL query that works, using a combination of unions and joins of tables that gives me the interim results I need.

```
SELECT  n.study_id AS StudyId,
        n.practice_id AS PracticeId,
    n.FluVaxCode,
    n.Date,
    date(p.BaseStart / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS BaseStart, 
    date(p.BaseEnd / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS BaseEnd,
    date(p.OutcomeStart / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS OutcomeStart, 
    date(p.OutcomeEnd / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS OutcomeEnd,
    CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN BaseStart AND BaseEnd THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS BaseVax,
    CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN OutcomeStart AND OutcomeEnd THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS OutcomeVax
FROM toypractice p INNER JOIN
     (SELECT  t.study_id, t.practice_id,
     date(t.event_date / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS Date, 
     t.code_id AS FluVaxCode
     FROM toytherapy t
     WHERE t.code_id IN ('dher.', 'a6b1.', 'bk31.')
     UNION 
     SELECT  c.study_id, c.practice_id, 
     DATE(c.event_date / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS Date, 
     c.code_id AS FluVaxCode
     FROM toyclinical c
     WHERE c.code_id IN ('1383.', '229..', 'X77RW')
     ORDER BY FluVaxCode DESC
     ) n 
     ON p.practice_id = n.practice_id;
```

I end up with multiple columns including three as:

```
Date, BaseStart, BaseEnd
```

all of which are in YYYY-MM-DD format (I think). Is there a way, during the query I can tack some code on the end of the query such that it will create a new column in the outputs, such that if Date falls between BaseStart and BaseEnd, the value in the new column will be 'Y', otherwise value in new column will be 'N'?  In this case I'm using sqlite to develop/test but it will eventually have to work in mssqlserver 2019.  Thx. J

Comment: See: CASE expressions and derived columns.

Comment: If you show your initial attempt or initial query, it will be easier to adjust the solution to incorporate your logic into the SQL.  Typically, this might be in the form of a derived table or CTE term, but it's not always necessary.

Comment: Your new SQL leaves another question.  `n.Date` is derived just like the other values.  They should be directly usable/comparable.  Something else might be missing.  If you can add the `CREATE TABLE` statements to the question, that might help.

Comment: If you had kept `event_date` exposed to the outer logic, you could have compared the raw values, before conversion.  There are lots of ways to structure this.

Comment: There's a one-line adjustment you should be able to make.  I've added that suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your current select list:

```
    , CASE WHEN n.Date BETWEEN date(p.BaseStart / 1000, 'unixepoch') AND date(p.BaseEnd / 1000, 'unixepoch') THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END AS is_between
```

This can be done in different ways.  But the above should work.

Here's another adjustment that should work.  I've added the original event_date to the result of the `n` derived table, plus added a corresponding `CASE` expression to the outer SELECT list.  The other CASE expressions probably need to be similarly adjusted.

```
SELECT n.study_id AS StudyId
     , n.practice_id AS PracticeId
     , n.FluVaxCode
     , n.Date
     , date(p.BaseStart / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS BaseStart
     , date(p.BaseEnd / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS BaseEnd
     , date(p.OutcomeStart / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS OutcomeStart
     , date(p.OutcomeEnd / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS OutcomeEnd
     , CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN BaseStart AND BaseEnd THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS BaseVax
     , CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN OutcomeStart AND OutcomeEnd THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS OutcomeVax
     , CASE WHEN n.event_date BETWEEN p.BaseStart AND p.BaseEnd THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END AS is_between
  FROM toypractice p
  JOIN (
         SELECT t.study_id, t.practice_id
              , t.event_date
              , date(t.event_date / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS Date
              , t.code_id AS FluVaxCode
           FROM toytherapy t
          WHERE t.code_id IN ('dher.', 'a6b1.', 'bk31.')
          UNION 
         SELECT c.study_id, c.practice_id
              , c.event_date
              , DATE(c.event_date / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS Date
              , c.code_id AS FluVaxCode
           FROM toyclinical c
          WHERE c.code_id IN ('1383.', '229..', 'X77RW')
          ORDER BY FluVaxCode DESC
       ) n 
    ON p.practice_id = n.practice_id
;
```

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f0be6116f31f518265dcba5b4f853e6e)

Something like this:

Specific test case for sqlite, as a starting point.

- cte  - provides a couple of rows representing your current query result
- cte2 - shows how we can convert the date (conv_date) to be compatible with the Base values
- Final query expression - shows how to use the derived conv_date from cte2 to calculate BETWEEN properly.

Notice, I left the attempt to use date directly, which produces the wrong `is_between` result.  `is_between2` shows the correct result.

```
WITH cte (date, BaseStart, BaseEnd) AS (
         SELECT 1467241200000, '2016-06-20', '2016-06-30' UNION
         SELECT 1467241200000, '2017-06-20', '2017-06-30'
     )
SELECT date(date / 1000, 'unixepoch'), BaseStart, BaseEnd
     , CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN BaseStart AND BaseEnd THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END AS is_between
     , CASE WHEN date(date / 1000, 'unixepoch') BETWEEN BaseStart AND BaseEnd THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END AS is_between2
  FROM cte
;

and also:

WITH cte (date, BaseStart, BaseEnd) AS (
         SELECT 1467241200000, '2016-06-20', '2016-06-30' UNION
         SELECT 1467241200000, '2017-06-20', '2017-06-30'
     )
   , cte2 AS (
         SELECT *
              , date(date / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS conv_date
           FROM cte
     )
SELECT date(date / 1000, 'unixepoch'), BaseStart, BaseEnd
     , CASE WHEN Date      BETWEEN BaseStart AND BaseEnd THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END AS is_between
     , CASE WHEN conv_date BETWEEN BaseStart AND BaseEnd THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END AS is_between2
  FROM cte2
;
```

Result:

| date(date / 1000, 'unixepoch') | BaseStart | BaseEnd | is_between | is_between2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-06-29 | 2016-06-20 | 2016-06-30 | b | a |
| 2016-06-29 | 2017-06-20 | 2017-06-30 | b | b |

General answer:

```
SELECT Date, BaseStart, BaseEnd
     , CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN BaseStart AND BaseEnd THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END AS is_between
  FROM ( your SQL ) AS derived_table
;

or

WITH cte AS (
       your sql
     )
SELECT Date, BaseStart, BaseEnd
     , CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN BaseStart AND BaseEnd THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END AS is_between
  FROM cte
;
```

You may need to add quoting if you chose identifiers which conflict with reserved or keywords in the SQL language supported by your database.

Comment: Thx. Jon.  I now have another small problem.  In the database I've been given, the dates are stored as long digits such as 1,467,241,200,000.  In my SQL query I converted them to YYYY-MM-DD by using "date(value / 1000, 'unixepoch') but then the BETWEEN check does not work.  Can I convert them to something humanly visible such that the BETWEEN check will also work properly?

Comment: @JimMaas Adding some kind of runnable test case to the question would help, so that we can see the actual types, data and calculations.  Generally, you'll want to use values which are consistent and orderable.  Whether you use all converted values or non-converted values, doesn't really matter.  When you use the BETWEEN operator, all the operands need to be consistent.  Notice, you haven't shown any indication of what Date, BaseStart or BaseEnd represent/contain in the question.  Without the test case, we are left to assume or guess.

Comment: @JimMaas Notice in your question you have: _all of which are in YYYY-MM-DD format_ .. Is this not true?  Even if true, provide actual examples in the test case.  Remember, your test case can be very trivial, with just enough detail to handle this specific question about deriving the BETWEEN indication.

Comment: Thx. Jon. Appreciate what you are suggesting, don't know how to provide a running test case outwith providing everything including the database.  Suggestions?

Comment: @JimMaas Start with providing the database you are using.  Are you using sqlite?  I'll add a kind of test case to my answer.  You might find it helpful :)  Solution updated.

Comment: I'm using sqlite on ubuntu linux with a toy database (subset of original mssql-server) to develop, but eventually it will have to work on mssql-server.  I realise there are some syntax differences but hopefully not too many to change.  I'm sure I will find it helpful, appreciate the patience!  I will also edit my question and provide complete sql code, might be enlightening ... ??

Comment: @JimMaas Read my updated answer carefully.  It contains a working solution.  I'll add a link to the fiddle.

Comment: Thx. Jon.  The one liner at the top works for me but I really don't understand why I have to keep giving it '(date / 1000, 'unixepoch') ' over and over again.  I would have thought that once it was converted to a date that SQL would save it that way and know what it had?

Comment: @JimMaas That's a derived column.  Just because you used the same column name for your derived column doesn't mean it changes the underlying data.  To use that derived column, you need to either derive the column in a derived table or CTE (Common Table Expression) and then use the new column name in the outer query expression, just as I was attempting to illustrate in my answer and the fiddle.  You can't refer to a derived column in the same select list.

Comment: @JimMaas If the answer is acceptable, you can accept it (with the checkmark), and then ask a new question about derived columns.  But first review all the various questions in SO that ask very similar questions.  It's a common misunderstanding.